# strange downloading error (wp7+skydrive api)

Tags: c#, windows-phone, onedrive

If the filename contains **#** - download from skydrive fails. More precisely - length of result always 0. Other files are loaded without any problems;

Thanks

start downloading:

```
if (!loading) {
                if (!Storage.Exists(item.Name)
                    || MessageBox.Show(AppResources.alreadyExists, AppResources.confirmation, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK) {
                    loading = true;
                    App.loadInfo.Name = item.Name;
                    App.loadInfo.Info = AppResources.loadingStart;
                    PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disa bled;
                    client.DownloadAsync(item.Id + CONTENT, item);
                }
            }
```

download completed:

```
void client_DownloadCompleted(object sender, LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs e) {
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;
        try {
            FileItem item = e.UserState as FileItem;
            if (e.Error == null
                && !e.Cancelled
                && e.UserState != null
                && item.Size == e.Result.Length.ToString()) //LENGTH = 0 { Storage.SaveFile(item.Name, e.Result);
                App.loadInfo.Info = AppResources.loadingComplete;
                new GetIcon(item._name);
            }
            else {
                if (item != null) App.loadInfo.Name = item.Name;
                App.loadInfo.Info = AppResources.loadingError;
            }
        }
        finally { App.loadInfo.Progress = 0; loading = false; MakeUi(); }
    }
```

LiveDownloadProgressChangedEventArgs does not arise

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Live Connect & Live SDK Known Issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/82d83c67-a250-4022-a702-458b7a3f62c1)

Answer (score 0):

If this is genuinely the case, can you not just strip the fragments from the URI before you make the request?

Comment: request uri not using filename directly. for sample       _client.DownloadAsync(file.e7982fae8124d253.E7982GFE8124D253!146/content);_ but i'm noticed that in this case filename on the server contains #   ps. sorry for my english